# NodeJS: Get Count By Month-Year

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some transactional data which looks as below:

```
    [{UserId: 19156, createdAt: "2014-03-01T18:30:00.000Z", …},
    {UserId: 19150, createdAt: "2014-03-09T18:30:00.000Z", …},
    {UserId: 18459, createdAt: "2014-04-09T18:30:00.000Z", …},
    {UserId: 19666, createdAt: "2014-10-24T07:12:05.000Z", …}]
```

My requirement it to get count by month-year, so that the output looks like below:

```
[{period: '2014-03', count:2}
{period: '2014-04', count:1},
{period: '2014-10', count:1}]
```

I'm doing this in Nodejs, and am just not able to work with the date to make this happen.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  take the substring of date , take the unique and count the frequency of each date

```js
const arr = [{UserId: 19156, createdAt: "2014-03-01T18:30:00.000Z",},
    {UserId: 19150, createdAt: "2014-03-09T18:30:00.000Z"},
    {UserId: 18459, createdAt: "2014-04-09T18:30:00.000Z"},
    {UserId: 19666, createdAt: "2014-10-24T07:12:05.000Z"}]

//take substring and just grab unique date
let distict_dates = [...new Set(arr.map(a => a.createdAt.substring(0, 7)))];
//count each date frequency
let reduced = distict_dates.map(a => {
        return {
            userCount: arr.filter(a1 => a1.createdAt.startsWith(a)).length,
            createdAt: a
        }
    }
)

console.log(reduced);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the code given below to group based on period year and month.

```
let array = [{ UserId: 19156, createdAt: "2014-03-01T18:30:00.000Z" },
{ UserId: 19150, createdAt: "2014-03-09T18:30:00.000Z" },
{ UserId: 18459, createdAt: "2014-04-09T18:30:00.000Z" },
{ UserId: 19666, createdAt: "2014-10-24T07:12:05.000Z" }]


function count(array) {
    return array.reduce((total, elem) => {
        let temp = elem.createdAt.split("-")
        let groupKey = temp[0] + "-" + temp[1];

        total[groupKey] ? total[groupKey] +=1: total[groupKey] = 1;
        // total[groupKey] += 1;
        return total
    }, {})
}

console.log(count(array))
```

The output of code above will be

```
{ '2014-03': 2, '2014-04': 1, '2014-10': 1 }
```

Of course you can easily convert from JSON format to array format using code given below

```
function convertToArray(json_data) {
    let result = [];
    for (var i in json_data)
        result.push({ period: i, count: json_data[i] });
    return result;
}
```

The output will be

```
[ { period: '2014-03', count: 2 },
  { period: '2014-04', count: 1 },
  { period: '2014-10', count: 1 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this method basically:

```
.reduce((acc = {}, i) => {
let period = i.createdAt.slice(0,7);
        acc[period] = {period, count: acc[period] ? acc[period].count+1: 1}
     return acc;
    }, {})
```

```js
   let t = [{UserId: 19156, createdAt: "2014-03-01T18:30:00.000Z"},
    {UserId: 19150, createdAt: "2014-03-09T18:30:00.000Z"},
    {UserId: 18459, createdAt: "2014-04-09T18:30:00.000Z"},
    {UserId: 19666, createdAt: "2014-10-24T07:12:05.000Z"}].reduce((acc = {}, i) => {
let period = i.createdAt.slice(0,7);
     acc[period] = {period, count: acc[period] ? acc[period].count+1: 1}
     return acc;
    }, {})

console.log(t);
// if you need exact same result then do it like this
console.log(Object.values(t));
```

Comment: You just need to console the final result

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
db.doc.aggregate([{ $group: {
                    _id:null,
                    period: { 
                    $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m", date: "$createdAt" } }, 
                      count: { $sum: 1 } },
        ]
    ).then()
```

Answer (score 0):

using aggregation:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
             period:{$dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m",date:"$createdAt"}}
         }
    },{
        $group:{ _id : {period : "$period"},count:{$sum:1}}
    },
      { $sort : { _id : 1 } }
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the createdAt is a string, convert string to date as follows

```
var t = Date.parse("2015-04-01T18:30:00.000Z");
var date = new Date(d)
```

Now get the year and month as follows

```
date.getMonth() // zero indexed
date.getFullYear()
```

Append them and form your required string format for createdAt

Comment: Ok, I'll try. And whats the best way to aggregate it?